# Set a pin HIGH when crash occurs

Tags: esp8266

I'm using an ESP8266 (NodeMCU v3). I want to set a PIN high if a `soft wdt reset` occurs (not expecting one). Is there a way I can do that?

Can I attach something on TX pin of the board and watch for crash dump? Maybe another Arduino?

Comment: Only after a crash? After normal reboot, the pin start LOW?

Comment: Look this link: https://www.megunolink.com/articles/how-to-detect-lockups-using-the-arduino-watchdog/

Comment: @LookAlterno that's a very useful article and program but it's pretty architecture specific. I don't think there is any way to use it with ESP8266 without an almost complete rewrite of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The ESP provides a reset reason API, which lets you differentiate between a crash and a normal reset:

```
extern "C" {
  #include "user_interface.h"
}

const char * const RST_REASONS[] =
{
  "REASON_DEFAULT_RST",
  "REASON_WDT_RST",
  "REASON_EXCEPTION_RST",
  "REASON_SOFT_WDT_RST",
  "REASON_SOFT_RESTART",
  "REASON_DEEP_SLEEP_AWAKE",
  "REASON_EXT_SYS_RST"
};

// .. in setup():

const rst_info * resetInfo = system_get_rst_info(); //populate reset info
String diag = String(RST_REASONS[resetInfo->reason]); // turn enum index to string

if(diag == "REASON_SOFT_WDT_RST") digitalWrite(TX, HIGH);// check string, take action
```

Answer (score 0):

The ESP8266 should  hold the pin LOW when it is active, letting it go high then signals that the program has crashed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the matter? I  need something like that for a project.

Comment: It sounds like the idea is to drive the pin low when operating properly, but rely on the WDT-triggered reset making it a high impedance input which can be overridden by an external pullup resistor.